# 'this' keyword in array prototype function is undefined

Tags: javascript

I would like to write my own function for every array and I'm using the `prototype` keyword.

The problem is that when I created the following script:

```
Array.prototype.test = () => {console.log('length: ',this.length)};

const result = [1,2,3].test();
```

If I run it in the console of chrome I get the following result:

```
length:  0
```

If I run it on my local machine with `node script.js` I get the following result:

```
length:  undefined
```

Why is `this.length` different and why it doesn't reflect the length of the array I'm calling the function on?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the arrow function syntax. The arrow function does not possess a `this` context, so it "points" to the global context.

The solution is simple:

```
Array.prototype.test = function() {console.log('length: ', this.length)};

const result = [1,2,3].test(); // length:  3
```

By adding explicitly `function` now your context (this) points to the object calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `arrow function` syntax.

When the "this" keyword are being called, it falls back into the global object.

In the `browser` it falls back into the `window object` and for this  reason it's  return 0 length.

But in the `global node object`, the length is undefined.

Instead, use the `function` keyword to get the `Array.prototype` context.

```
Array.prototype.test = function(){console.log('length: ',this.length)};
```